# Integral domains $A \subseteq B$ that satisfy $Q(A) \cap B= A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, extension-field

Let $A \subseteq B$ be integral domains with fields of fractions $Q(A) \subseteq Q(B)$.
Assume that $Q(A) \cap B=A$.

> What additional conditions are needed in order to guarantee that the following property holds: If $w \in B$ is algebraic over $A$, and $\sum \hat{a_i} w^i \in B$, for some $\hat{a_i} \in Q(A)$, then $\hat{a_i} \in A$.

**Remarks:**
(1) Of course, if $\hat{a_i} \in B$, then $\hat{a_i} \in A$.
(2) There is a nice theorem by H. Bass that appears in [van den Essen's book about the JC](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764363505) and in [Remark after Corollary 1.3, page 74](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=2n7kBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=differential%20structure%20of%20etale&source=bl&ots=CwQzAR6_t_&sig=rj20DhcGt_XYgc-SZABpYbgbmis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSypnWjILUAhVGWxQKHSHxDs0Q6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=differential%20structure%20of%20etale&f=false); it presents conditions on two integral domains $A \subseteq B$ implying that $Q(A) \cap B=A$, but here I am assuming that we already know that this equality is satisfied.

Thank you very much for any hints!