# Does $\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}b \in B$, $Q(A) \cap B = A$, imply $\frac{a_1}{a_2} \in A$ and $\frac{a_3}{a_4}\in A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A \subseteq B$ be an algebraic ring extension of integral domains having fields of fractions $Q(A) \subseteq Q(B)$.
Further assume that $Q(A) \cap B = A$.
Take $b \in B-A$, $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 \in A$ with $a_2a_4 \neq 0$, and denote $w:=\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}b$. Of course, $w \in Q(B)$.

> Is it true that if $w \in B$, then $\frac{a_1}{a_2} \in A$ and $\frac{a_3}{a_4}\in A$?

This question is a special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291220/a-certain-property-of-integral-domains-a-subseteq-b-that-satisfy-qa-cap-b), which allows powers of $b$.

Any comments are welcome.

**Edit:**
After receiving a counter-example, I would like to add the condition that $A \subset B$ is a separable ring extension; is my claim true in this case?

---

**Edit 2:** If $A,B$ are UFD's and every irreducible element of $A$ remains irreducible in $B$, then the claim is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=K[x], B=k[y]$ with $y^2=x$.

If we set $b=xy$, $a_1=0,a_2=a_3=1,a_4=x$, then $w=y\in B$, but $\frac{a_3}{a_4}=\frac{1}{x} \not \in A$

Comment: Nice example, thanks! In your example, $K[y^2] \subset K[y]$ is not separable, according to Corollary 8 of Wang http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869380902331/1-s2.0-0021869380902331-main.pdf?_tid=68c22b6e-6ace-11e7-bb37-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1500282221_918b126f8e7474f5a1a45ac6d5b0e761. because $2y$ is not invertible in $K[y]$. Please, do you have a counter-example with $A \subset B$ separable?

Comment: Let $A=K[x]_{(x)]$, $B=K(x)=A[y]/(xy-1)$ and take $b=x$. Then $\frac{1}{x} b \in B$ but $\frac{1}{x} \not \in A$.

Comment: Thank you! Please what is your new $A$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know why I cannot edit my comment but $A$ should be $K[x]_{(x)}=\{ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} | f(x),g(x) \in K[x], g(x) \neq 0\}$, the localization of $K[x]$ at the prime ideal $(x)$.

Comment: Very nice! If I am not wrong, I think I have once founded your first counter-example, but not your second. Do you think there is any chance to have a positive answer to my claim? What additional conditions are needed? (let's deal with a simple ring extension $A \subset A[b]$).

Comment: I have just noticed that your $b$ does not satisfy $b \in B-A$, since it is already in $A$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I should mean $b=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Sorry, what is $\frac{a_3}{a_4}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$, or anything not belongs to $A$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much! However, it does not satisfy (1) of my edit, but it is still a nice idea.

Comment: (Perhaps I should ask a new question, with more precise conditions).

Comment: I also requiered $Q(A) \cap B=A$, which is not satisfied by your second idea.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for that

Comment: Thank you very much anyway! Further ideas are welcome.