# A certain property of a separable ring extension $A \subseteq B$ with $Q(A) \cap B=A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-module

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356663/does-fraca-1a-2-fraca-3a-4b-in-b-qa-cap-b-a-imply-fraca) and getting an answer (a counterexample),
I wish to further assume that the ring extension $A \subseteq B$ is separable,
namely, $B$ is a projective $B \otimes_A B$-module, see also [this blog](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/separable-algebras/).

More elaborately,
Let $A \subseteq B$ be an algebraic *separable* ring extension of integral domains having fields of fractions $Q(A) \subseteq Q(B)$.
Further assume that $Q(A) \cap B = A$.
Take $b \in B-A$, $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 \in A$ with $a_2a_4 \neq 0$, and denote $w:=\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}b$. Of course, $w \in Q(B)$.

> Is it true that if $w \in B$, then $\frac{a_1}{a_2} \in A$ and $\frac{a_3}{a_4}\in A$?

Notice that it is enough to show that 
$\frac{a_1}{a_2} \in B$ and $\frac{a_3}{a_4}\in B$,
since then $Q(A) \cap B = A$ implies that
$\frac{a_1}{a_2} \in A$ and $\frac{a_3}{a_4}\in A$.

Perhaps it would be easier to answer my question if we further assume that:
**(1)** $A^*=B^*=k^*=k-\{0\}$, where $k$ is the base field; in that case, my question becomes: Is it true that if $w \in B$ then $a_2 \in k^*$ and $a_4 \in k^*$?
**(2)** Both $A$ and $B$ are UFD's.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I almost have a proof for the above. I will think about it a little more and write my partial answer here. (hint: divide into two cases $a_4$ is invertible in $A$ or not). Remark: I assume that $A^*=B^*=k^*$.