# An integral domain $R$ having a subring $S$ such that $Q(S) \cap R=S$

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a (commutative) integral domain. Denote the field of fractions of $R$ by $Q(R)$.

Assume that $S \subseteq R$ is a subring of $R$, denote the field of fractions of $S$ by $Q(S)$ and further assume that:
$Q(S) \cap R=S$ (of course, we always have $Q(S) \cap R \supseteq S$).

I wonder if the following claim is true:

> If $\sum_i \tilde{s_i} r^i \in R$, where $\tilde{s_i} \in Q(S), r \in R$,
>   then necessarily $\tilde{s_i} \in R$ or $r \in S$.
>   In other words, if $\sum_i \tilde{s_i} r^i \in R$, where $\tilde{s_i} \in Q(S), r \in R$,
>   then necessarily $\tilde{s_i} \in S$ or $r \in S$.

**Remark:** Probably, the answer depends on the specific $R$ and $S$ or on connections between them, for example flatness of $S \subseteq R$ etc.

**Edit:** An easy counterexample is presented in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356663/does-fraca-1a-2-fraca-3a-4b-in-b-qa-cap-b-a-imply-fraca?rq=1) question:
$S=k[y^2], R=k[y], \tilde{s_1}=\frac{1}{y^2}, r=y^3$; indeed,
$\tilde{s_1}r=\frac{1}{y^2}y^3=y \in k[y]$ with $\tilde{s_1}=\frac{1}{y^2} \notin 
k[y]$ and $r=y^3 \notin k[y^2]$.

Therefore, I would like to ask:

> Are there additional conditions guaranteeing the following property to be satisfied: 
>   If $\sum_i \tilde{s_i} r^i \in R$, where $\tilde{s_i} \in Q(S), r \in R$,
>   then necessarily $\tilde{s_i} \in S$ or $r \in S$.

Examples for additional conditions:

**(a)** $S \subseteq R$ is separable. 
**(b)** The only invertible elements of $S$ and $R$ are $k^*=k-\{0\}$, where $k$ is the base field.

(In the counterexample, $S \subseteq R$ is integral, so we see that integrality will not help. $R=k[y]=k[y^2][y]=S[y]$, so being simple will not help also).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like some Lemma of Gauss thingy.

Comment: @ε--δ, thank you. Please, could you elaborate your idea?

Comment: Please, did you mean to apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)? But perhaps only in special cases such as UFD's?

Comment: No, it just reminded me to that theorem. It is very possibly of no use here. Just a random comment and not an idea.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: $(\frac1s)s=1\in R$ and $\frac1s\notin S$ unless $s$ is invertible.

Comment: @user26857, oh nice, thanks. So I should have required that $r \in R-S$ or something similar. I will edit my question.